# Angular Material Select - How to set value programatically?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a form with a select input as a component - so the form component holds children components for each field type (text, select, textarea, etc.). I want to be able to load data and display it in the form . The problem is with the material-select, i can't set value , i've read about using [compareWith] directive - but i don't know how to trigger it.
To simulate sending the data to the i've created a button that changes the @Input value in the Select Component and by that - triggers the [compareWith] - but i guess it's not the solution.

Here is the main component structure :

```
 <form [formGroup]="contactForm" >
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Full Name </mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Full Name" value="" formControlName="fullName">
    </mat-form-field>
  <br>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Email </mat-label>
      <input type = "email" matInput placeholder="Email" value="" formControlName="email">
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    // select component *
    <select-multiple-example [formObj]="contactForm" [selectedValue]="selectedVal">
    </select-multiple-example>
  </form>
  
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="setSelectValue()">set value</button>
```

I'm adding 2 examples for better understanding of the issue:

- The first is my attempt to trigger the select-multiple-example and set a value from it's input
- The second is a working example of setting a value ad a standalone component

[Example of the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqu7nc-zcs7ro?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-component%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)

[Example of the selection working as an independent component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-t8rp7j?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It is working on "example of the problem" link.

Comment: Ah do you mean, that if I uncheck "second", the button "set value" should check "second"?

Comment: I'll elaborate - the "set value" button is suppose to set value to the "select program" dropdown, which is a child component, the value that's being set from the button function is "second", so the working scenario will be that once you'll click "set value" - > the dropdown will show "second"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh ok, basically you want to trigger an event on child component whenever an input value changes on parent.

First of all you should get a reference of your child component from your parent to access it within code with `ViewChild(ren)`, then if you click on button, you should trigger an event, or a function that changes the value inside the child component.

But, this can also be achieved with the examples you provided using `ngOnChanges`.

The first problem here is that you're trying to access an input value inside `constructor`. You can't do that. `constructors` are typescript things, `@Input`s are Angular things. Your input variable will be available on `ngOnInit`.

So, move `formObj` assignation to `ngOnInit`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myprgrmFormControl = this.formObj
  }
```

Then, you can access changed variable inside `ngOnChanges`

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.myprgrmFormControl.get('program').setValue([changes.selectedValue.currentValue])
  }
```

Comment: Thanks - i've updated the example - but i didn't used ViewChild(ren), i've passed the form object in the @input

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to check out the `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle function (onInit, onDestroy, onChange, etc...). This way you will be able to see the changes in the parent component and react on it. Let me know if I understood well your issue!

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay - i'll elaborate - i want to checkout any function lifecycle function that will trigger the event that "refresh" the dropdown, so , once the "set value" will pressed - it will "emit" the new value from the parent component to the child (select-multiple-example) - i'm not sure i've implemented the right solution....  if you'll look in the second example - you'll see the behaviour i'm looking for - only as a child component.